# User Control error Object reference not set to an instance of an object?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have two `WebUserControl`.

```
1. UC_1.axcx
2. UC_2.ascx
```

I tried to access `UC_2.ascx.cs` method from my `UC_1.axcx.cs`. Below is 
`UC_1.ascx.cs` method.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UC_2 objUC = new UC_2();
    objUC.assignName("123');
}
```

`UC_2.ascx.cs`:

```
public string assignName(string nameParam)
{
  TextBox1.Text = nameParam;   //Here i am getting object null error.
  retrun "access UC_2 successfully.";
}
```

While accessing `UC_2` method from `UC_1`, I am getting:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

How to solve this issue ?

Comment: Who creates the TextBox1? In any case, recommended reading [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: In My UC_2.ascx I have <asp:TextBox id="TexBox1" Text="test" runat="server"/>. So i would like replace value "test" tp "123" whhile assign the value via UC_1. That time i am getting null reference issue.

Comment: I can't understand your recommended link. Can you please help me to solve

Answer (score 2):

You need to register `UC_2.ascx` in `UC_1.ascx` instead of instantiate it. in `UC_1.ascx` :

```
<%@ Register Src="~/UC_2.ascx" TagPrefix="uc1" TagName="UC_2" %>

<uc1:UC_2 runat="server" ID="UC_2" />
```

And in the `UC_1` code behind change `Page_Load` like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UC_2.assignName("123");
}
```

**Edit**: To call `UC2` method dynamically without register in `ascx`, Try this:

```
var Uctrl = (UC_2)LoadControl("~/UC_2.ascx"); 
Controls.Add(Uctrl);
Uctrl.assignName("123");
```

Comment: If it's possbile to call UC2 method dynamically without register in ascx.