# Table User Control - Accessing checkboxes in UC

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've created a Table User control. In each cell in table, there are checkboxes. How can I access the attributes of selected checkboxes in the default.aspx page.

I've dragged Table user control into default.aspx

```
  <uc1:SchTable ID="SchTime1" runat="server" />
```

Am relatively new to User Control. Was trying it out because of maintainability.
I managed to get the codes to work by hard coding the table (not using user control) on the same page as default.aspx though

Comment: Check this answer may helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31358272/2946329

Answer (score 0):

Add a property to the UserControl that accesses and returns the data you want.

In `SchTable` you can add any number of public properties and methods you want. Some examples:

```
public IEnumerable<ListItem> SelectedItems
{
   get 
   {
       return ACheckboxList.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Where(i => i.Selected); 
   }
}

public IEnumerable<Checkbox> GetAllCheckboxes()
{
     //Find and return the checkboxes here just like you would in the page
}
```

And then in the `Default` page, you can access that information:

```
var selected = SchTime1.SelectedItems;
var checkboxes = SchTime1.GetAllCheckboxes();
```

There is a MSDN tutorial [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3457w616.aspx) that goes more into details on all this.